# Will group cordinator treat kafka consumer (0.9) dead if it doesn't call poll() for a very long time?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html mentions that *"As long the consumer is sending heartbeats in regular intervals, it is assumed to be alive, well and processing messages from its partitions. In fact, the act of polling for messages is what causes the consumer to send those heartbeats. If the consumer stops sending heartbeats for long enough, its session will time out and the group coordinator will consider it dead and trigger a rebalance."*

Similarly https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html specifies that *"The broker will automatically detect failed processes in the test group by using a heartbeat mechanism. The consumer will automatically ping the cluster periodically, which lets the cluster know that it is alive. As long as the consumer is able to do this it is considered alive and retains the right to consume from the partitions assigned to it. If it stops heartbeating for a period of time longer than session.timeout.ms then it will be considered dead and its partitions will be assigned to another process. "*

In my application, the processing of messages received from previous poll() can take upto hours before it calls another poll(). Note: I disable auto commit because I don't always know how long it would take to process all the previous messages.

a) Will that cause group coordinator to consider the consumer dead or inactive?

b) Are there other ways to send heartbeat messages to group coordinator to keep the session active?

c) Will session.timeout.ms have any effect here on keeping consumer alive/active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) Yes, if you do not call `poll()` for longer than `session.timeout.ms` Kafka considers the consumer as dead.

b) As an alternative, you could call `poll()` during processing (ie, interleaved with processing) to trigger a heart beat (and seek before each "real" poll). Using an extra processing thread would also be possible, allowing the main thread to poll regularly for sending heart beat. **However, you need to ensure that failures on the processing thread are detected (what is tricky to do correctly)!**

c) You could increase the timeout value, however, this might not be what you want, as if your consumer fails, this failure gets detected very late.

The problem you describe is actually known, and the consumer behavior might change in the future. There is already a discussion about it. See [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) for more details.

**Update**

Since Kafka `0.10.1` a consumer has two configuration parameters: `max.poll.interval.ms` and `session.timeout.ms`. The first is the max time between two consecutive polls, while the second is the heartbeat timeout. Heartbeats are send in an extra thread and thus decoupled from calling `poll()` now. Thus, increasing `max.poll.interval.ms` does not have the negative effect that a failure of the whole client (no heartbeat) is not detected quickly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to existing KIP for this issue. Taking your suggestion b), seems like I could create a new thread after each poll() call in main thread and have it periodically (using sleep()) call its own poll() starting with lowest offset that main thread got from its recent poll(). Once main thread is done processing all its messages from previous poll(), I can terminate the new thread. Does this seem like a good approach?

Comment: Yes. Both threads need to use same consumer object/instance! Otherwise, they are treated as two consumers. That's why you need to seek to correct position before each real poll (heart bear poll might alter consumer position).

Comment: After further reading seems consumer instance is not multi-thread safe so sound like there needs to be another way to keep the consumer alive.

Comment: You are right, it is not thread safe (that the reason why (b) is hard to get right...). As explained in the answer, either you `poll` regularly or you increase the timeout. KIP-62 will fix this issues in the future. I do not have any better advice. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Seems KI-62 is already released in 0.10.1.0 but I can't find a download for this version anywhere. Any idea?

Comment: `0.10.1.0` is not released yet, but should be available in the next couple of weeks.